# Install jmespth-term in Mac OSx

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, jmespath

I am unable to install [jmespath-term](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.terminal)

It gives me :

```
>> sudo pip install jmespath-term

Collecting jmespath-term
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement jmespath-term
  No distributions at all found for jmespath-term
```

Python Version

```
python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

Pip Version

```
pip --version
pip 6.0.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.3-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jmespath-term` appears to have an alternate name in the `pypi` index:

Doing a search with pip (`pip search jmespath-term`) returns:

```
jmespath-terminal         - JMESPath Terminal
```

So `pip install jmespath-terminal` should work for you.

Comment: `pip3 install jmespath-terminal` installed properly on MacOS 12.6.1, Python 3.10.8, pip 22.3.1 after many unsuccessful attempts with prior versions of python3 and pip3.